# How to know if user is logged in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to know if a user is logged in with zend framework.
I have my LoginController who create a instance of Zend_Auth, but I don't know how to do to check if the user is really logged in ...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should give us your code ...
Then, if you want to know if a user is logged in, you can do it like that

```
if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()){
   //user is logged in
}else{
   //user not logged in
}
```

You could also make some search by yourself
[How to check if user is logged with Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518450/how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-with-zend-framework)
[how to get currently logged user details zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848578/how-to-get-currently-logged-user-details-zend-framework?rq=1)